# Doquier, dondequiera, adondequiera?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática

Es normal escuchar esta palabras, pero ¿verlas escritas? Es molesto, por lo menos para mi ver esas palabras así. ¿Están realmente bien escritas? Parece ser que *doquier* es una abreviatura de *dondequiera*. ¿No significarían lo mismo donde quiera y a donde quiera que sus formas en bloque?

Referencia: http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/doquier

Comment: Hola Theia, ¡interesante pregunta otra vez! Sería beneficiososo que compartieras tus investigaciones previas: ¿qué resultados dio tu búsqueda en el DLE o el DPD? Así será más fácil andar por caminos nuevos y no repetir todo el proceso qie ya hayas hecho.

Comment: Hola @fedorqui. Puse referencia a la palabara "doquier" aunque no he averiguado mucho sobre esto.

Answer (score 3):

A diferencia de "[dondequiera](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=gb4MIefg3D6zuBo1Id)" y "[adondequiera](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=nrx0l9mNKD6b6hKfZh)", que van seguidos de una relativa con "que", la palabra "doquier" se usa sola. Una de las combinaciones más habituales (en realidad, la única que me viene a la mente) es "por doquier" (que significa "por todas partes").

"Dondequiera" y "adondequiera" son respectivamente equiparables a "en cualquier lugar" y "a cualquier lugar", y siempre sirven de antecedente a una relativa. El "quiera" que las conforma es impersonal y no debe confundirse con el "quiera" personal correspondiente a la primera o tercera persona del singular, en cuyo caso se debe escribir por separado:

- Irás a donde (yo) quiera que vayas.
- Dejaré el presente donde (él/ella) quiera que lo deje.

En estos casos, "que" introduce una proposición nominal: Yo/Él/Ella quiero/e que ...

Para comprobar que "dondequiera" y "adondequiera" son impersonales y deben escribirse como una sola palabra, debemos poder reemplazar esas palabras por las frases, también impersonales, "(a) donde sea/fuera que".

Answer (score 2):

Sobre la forma correcta de escribir estas palabras parece haber discrepancias entre el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas y el Diccionario de la lengua española:
Sobre **dondequiera** el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=gb4MIefg3D6zuBo1Id) indica que "... ha de escribirse hoy **en una sola palabra** ..." [negritas mías], mientras que el [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E8JIKmq) recoge como válido también la forma separada "**donde quiera**".
Lo mismo ocurre en el caso de **adondequiera**: el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=nrx0l9mNKD6b6hKfZh) indica que "...No se admite su escritura en dos palabras..." y el [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0o1XiDN) recoge también la forma separada.
Finalmente, en cuanto a **doquier**, no figura en el DPD, mientras que el [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E8yw125) recoge las dos formas: **doquier** y **do quier**.

Answer (score 1):

En español existen relativos inespecíficos que son términos compuestos formados por un relativo (quien, como, donde, adonde, cuando) más la forma verbal gramaticalizada quiera. Así tenemos: quienquiera, comoquiera, dondequiera (doquiera), adondequiera y cuandoquiera, estos últimos menos usados. Indican personas o cosas no identificadas y su significado equivale a ‘sea quien sea’, ‘sea como sea’.

En cuanto a su escritura, el segmento quiera no se escribe nunca separado del relativo, pues si se separan equivaldrían a la forma del verbo querer precedida de un adverbio relativo. Así tenemos que es diferente Triunfará dondequiera que vaya y Que vaya donde quiera. En el primer caso significa ‘donde sea’ y en el segundo, ‘al lugar que desee’.

Si cambiamos al plural: Triunfarán dondequiera que vayan; Que vayan donde quieran, nos damos cuenta de que la forma compuesta no varía mientras que, en la segunda opción, concuerda con el verbo principal (vayan)

Fuente: http://udep.edu.pe/castellanoactual/dondequiera-no-es-donde-quiera/

Comment: ¿Has visto las entradas del DLE http://dle.rae.es/?id=E8JIKmq http://dle.rae.es/?id=0o1XiDN y http://dle.rae.es/?id=E8yw125 que recogen como validas "donde quiera", "adonde quiera" y "do quier"? Parecen sugerir que, por ejemplo, es igual de correcto "triunfará **dondequiera** que vaya" y "triunfará **donde quiera** que vaya"