# Wherever translations

Tags: traducción, adverbios

I just a quick question regarding the translation of "wherever."

From what I've seen, we can say:

- *Donde + verbo*
- *Dondequiera/Adondequiera que + verbo* (typically where the verb is *ser*)

Is there a difference between the two forms, or are they synonymous and interchangeable?

For example, to translate the sentence "We can eat wherever you want," would it be acceptable to say *Podemos comer donde quieras* or *Podemos comer dondequiera que sea*? Or is one used more frequently than the other?

Edit: the answers on [similar StackExchange page](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21494/doquier-dondequiera-adondequiera) didn't fully answer the frequency/commonality of usage.

Thanks!

Comment: Translation requests for simple words are **not** on-topic, but I'd argue that this is a bit more than that, because you've looked up the thing and still have doubts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doquier, dondequiera, adondequiera?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21494/doquier-dondequiera-adondequiera)

Comment: I'm now feeling doubtful that the proposed duplicate addresses the current question.

Comment: It depends on what the verb goes into the "Donde + verbo"?  If you mean the verb querer, than i believe that would be correct.  I'm not sure just any verb would work there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either *donde* or *dondequiera que* for the meaning that you've expressed in your examples. Using one or the other doesn't depend on the verb that follows. The main difference in meaning is that *dondequiera que* emphasizes the total freedom of the choice of place, while *donde* makes it sound more like you're asking for a specific place. Although no translations are exact, this is basically the same difference as between English "wherever" and "where" respectively.

There's however another important difference. *Dondequiera (que)* is a long, high-sounding phrase, and it doesn't belong in the informal register of a conversation. It sounds bookish, even archaic, or like something you might hear in a romantic song. You shouldn't often encounter people who say things like

- *Podemos comer dondequiera que gustes.* ("We can eat wherever you like.")
- *Adondequiera que iba me lo cruzaba.* ("Wherever I went I ran into him.")

even though they're grammatical. They're OK for a story with the proper context, or a piece of poetry, and they might be more common in the spoken language in some places, but I'd counsel it's best to avoid them. *Donde* is enough.

One thing you can do, though, if you think you need to emphasize the total freedom of "wher**ever**" in examples like the one you gave, is add some adverb like *más* or *mejor* to the verb expressing preference:

- *Podemos ir donde más te guste.* ("We can go wherever you like best.")
- *Podemos ir donde mejor te parezca.* ("We can go wherever you think best.")